# Self creating columns based on value in another

Tags: python, pandas

This is very similar to the question i asked yesterday. The aim is to be able to add a functionality which will allow for a column to be created depending on the value shown in another. For example, when it finds a country code in a specified file, i would like it to create a column with the name '*Country Code* Total', and sum the amount of units for every row with that same country code

This is what my script outputs at the moment:

[image: Script Output]

What i want to see:

[image: Goal]

My Script:

```
df['Sum of Revenue'] = df['Units Sold'] * df['Dealer Price']
    df['AR Revenue'] = df[]
    df = df.sort_values(['End Consumer Country', 'Currency Code'])
    # Sets first value of index by position
    df.loc[df.index[0], 'Unit Total'] = df['Units Sold'].sum()
    # Sets first value of index by position
    df.loc[df.index[0], 'Total Revenue'] = df['Sum of Revenue'].sum()
    # Sums the amout of Units with the End Consumer Country AR
    df['AR Total'] = df.loc[df['End Consumer Country'] == 'AR', 'Units Sold'].sum()
    # Sums the amount of Units with the End Consumer Country AU
    df['AU Total'] = df.loc[df['End Consumer Country'] == 'AU', 'Units Sold'].sum()
    # Sums the amount of Units with the End Consumer Country NZ
    df['NZ Total'] = df.loc[df['End Consumer Country'] == 'NZ', 'Units Sold'].sum()
```

However, as i know the countries that will come up in this file, i have added them accordingly to my script to find. How would i write my script so that if it finds another country code, for example GB, it would create a column called 'GB Total' and sum the units for every row with the country code set to GB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't quite how you want to join the results to your output, but the basic idea is instead of hard-coding each country, you could `groupby` and do all of the calculations at once: `df.groupby('End Consumer Country')['Units Sold'].sum()`. If you don't need every country found in your `DataFrame` then mask before the groupby.

Comment: @ALollz Hi mate, i already have a Unit total for the whole file. Now i just want the script to total the Units for each country code it finds. Would the `groupby` code like you mentioned work?

Comment: But adding a separate column for each country code it finds

Comment: Yes, the `groupby` will return a `Series`, with each Index being a unique country found in your `DataFrame` and the values being the sum of the units sold for that country.

Comment: But regardless, are you sure you want that organization in the end? `pandas` isn't excel, and you're going to have tons of excess `NaN` values because `DataFrames` are required to be rectangular. Adding several columns at only the first index of a `DataFrame` really isn't the norm. If the organization of your aggregation doesn't really match the organization of your underlying `DataFrame` it's typically better to just create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly need that format, then here is how I would proceed (starting data below):

```
# Get those first two columns
d = {'Sum of Revenue': 'Total Revenue', 'Units Sold': 'Total Sold'}
for col, newcol in d.items():
    df.loc[df.index[0], newcol] = df[col].sum()

# Add the rest for every country:
s = df.groupby('End Consumer Country')['Units Sold'].sum().to_frame().T.add_suffix(' Total')
s.index = [df.index[0]]

df  = pd.concat([df, s], 1, sort=False)
```

#### Output: `df`:

```
  End Consumer Country  Sum of Revenue  Units Sold  Total Revenue  Total Sold  AR Total  AU Total  NZ Total  US Total
a                   AR       13.486216           1     124.007334        28.0       3.0       7.0      11.0       7.0
b                   AR       25.984073           2            NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
c                   AU       21.697871           3            NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
d                   AU       10.962232           4            NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
e                   NZ       16.528398           5            NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
f                   NZ       29.908619           6            NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
g                   US        5.439925           7            NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

As you can see, `pandas` added a bunch of `NaN` values as we only assigned something to the first row, and a `DataFrame` must be rectangular

---

It's far simpler to have a different `DataFrame` that summarizes the totals and within each country. If this is fine, then everything simplifies to a single `.pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index='End Consumer Country', 
               values=['Sum of Revenue', 'Units Sold'],
               margins=True,
               aggfunc='sum').T.add_suffix(' Total)
```

#### Output:

```
End Consumer Country   AR Total   AU Total   NZ Total  US Total   All Total
Sum of Revenue        39.470289  32.660103  46.437018  5.439925  124.007334
Units Sold             3.000000   7.000000  11.000000  7.000000   28.000000
```

Same information, much simpler to code.

---

#### Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'End Consumer Country': ['AR', 'AR', 'AU', 'AU', 'NZ', 'NZ', 'US'],
                   'Sum of Revenue': np.random.normal(20,6,7),
                   'Units Sold': np.arange(1,8,1)},
                   index = list('abcdefg'))

  End Consumer Country  Sum of Revenue  Units Sold
a                   AR       13.486216           1
b                   AR       25.984073           2
c                   AU       21.697871           3
d                   AU       10.962232           4
e                   NZ       16.528398           5
f                   NZ       29.908619           6
g                   US        5.439925           7
```

Comment: This is great, the pivot table option is just what i'm looking for. How would i implement this into the code i have mentioned above. Am i replacing any of my code with the pivot table function, or just adding to my script?

Comment: I'm just confused how i would implement your code to what i have already, sorry if i'm being stupid

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you so much!